# Android: shutting down the phone programmatically

Tags: android, shutdown

Is it possible to shut down the whole phone by an app? How? Do I need to root the phone?

Comment: I wouldn't suggest designing your app in such a way that it distinguishes between "rooted" and "non-rooted" devices.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to shutdown an android mobile programatically?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10411650/how-to-shutdown-an-android-mobile-programatically)

Comment: Not possible unless your application is System app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need the DEVICE_POWER permission in order to shut the phone completely off which requires the device being rooted.

You can use the PowerManager to get it to sleep or reboot.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.html#reboot(java.lang.String)

Reboot also requires a permission:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#REBOOT

Answer (score 0):

#### 1、you device need root

#### 2、code like this

```
private void powerOff() {
    try {
        Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime()
                .exec(new String[]{ "su", "-c", "reboot -p" });
        proc.waitFor();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private void reboot() {
    try {
        Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{ "su", "-c", "reboot" });
        proc.waitFor();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```