# How to create a sleep timer app for android

Tags: android, timer

I want to create an app that can shutdown the phone after a time set by the user , I dont know really how to start .

Any help would be much appreciated .Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

For obvious reasons, you cannot power off a device programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

So far It's only possible with rooted device or app should be signed with the system firmware signing key.

```
try {
    Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime()
                    .exec(new String[]{ "su", "-c", "reboot -p" });
    proc.waitFor();
} catch (Exception ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

refs:

- [How to shutdown an android mobile programatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10411650/how-to-shutdown-an-android-mobile-programatically)
- [Programmatically switching off Android phone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3745523/programmatically-switching-off-android-phone)