# how to force turn off device?

Tags: java, android, powermanager

currently eclipse/android studio cannot build the app with error: undefined function gotosleep();

```
PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(POWER_SERVICE);
        pm.goToSleep(100);
```

here in the manifest added:

```
<uses-permission  android:name="android.permission.DEVICE_POWER"/>
```

and change package to:

```
android.uid.system
```

we dont want the device admin lock to make android sleep as it is different from PowerManager, and not sure if changing setting timeout would achieve similar result with PowerManager, but not sure if it can be wake up(turn screen on) programmatically.

Regards,
Vims

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10411650/how-to-shutdown-an-android-mobile-programatically

Comment: `goToSleep` metod is hidden, so you can call it only with reflection. But in that case - it likely requires some system only app permission.