# How to shutdown android device programmatically having DPM privileges(single app/Lock task mode) NON rooted?

Tags: android, shutdown, device-policy-manager, custom-rom

Developing an app to run in single app mode/Lock task mode having DPM(device policy manager) access and privileges, But how to make device to shutdown programmatically without rooting.

Tried these below links, but they work with system app or ROOTed device.

[Turn off device programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24693682/turn-off-device-programmatically)

[How to shutdown an Android mobile programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10411650/how-to-shutdown-an-android-mobile-programmatically)